# R XLConnect - saving in first blank row of xlsx file

Tags: r, excel, xlconnect

I want to save my data frames daily by R XLConnect formulas in one xlsx file one by one. Is it possible to save new report in first blank row in existing file?

Comment: Of course. Read in the data from that worksheet and when writing, skip that many rows.

Comment: Ok, what if reports are saved automatically every day and rows could be of different length?

Comment: Read in one of the columns and save from the first non-blank entry. Best answer would be if you did this with a simple XLS file, and showed the full input with `dput()`.

Comment: Have a look at XLConnect::appendWorksheet which should do what you are looking for

Comment: Thanks a lot, previous tip solved my problem.